# Question about <form onsubmit "function() ">

Tags: javascript, html

i have wrote a function to activate onsubmit"" in the form.
In the function(JavaScript) i try to fill variables with input from the fieldset.
On troubleshooting i immediately found out that all the input gets cleared before i can save them into the variables. 
I know that this is not how forms are used but i do like how it points out the fields that still needs to be filled.
so is there a way or someone how figured out a way to outsmart the submit to do something(function) before the refresh? or is there absolutely no way?

```
function objectfill() {
var vnaam = document.getElementById('Voornaam').value;
var anaam = document.getElementById('naam').value;
var mail = document.getElementById('email').value;
var tele = document.getElementById('mobiel').value;
var rknr = document.getElementById('rijksregister').value;
var actie = document.getElementById('workshop').value
var k = document.getElementsByName('Room');
var room
for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    if (k[i].checked) {
        room = k[i].value;
    }
}

var personeel = new personeelgegevens(pnr, vnaam, anaam, mail, tele, rknr, 
actie, room);
console.log(personeel)
```

This was the function i used onsubmit="objectfill()"
I wanted to fill the object but obviously not working.

Comment: Use `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from clearing, it will also prevent it from submitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to prevent that submit from happening so that your JavaScript can run, by calling [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). Also, try using [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event properties.

```
// Assuming a form that looks like
<form id="myform">

// Do

const form = document.getElementById('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  // prevent the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault()

  // The rest of your form code here
})
```